# How can I update column randomly in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and I want to update some columns in this table randomly.
This is my update script

```
update personnels set 

first_name=(select top 1 first_name from personnels order by NEWID()),
```

I tried this script but select top 1 first_name from personnels order by NEWID() query took too long. How can I update column efficiantly random.

Answer (score 2):

Try generating a Random sequence outside and update using a self-join. Something like this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEW_ID()),
        FristName
        FROM personnels 
),C2
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEW_ID()),
        FristName
        FROM personnels 
)
UPDATE C2
    SET
        FristName = CTE.FristName
    FROM C2
        INNER JOIN CTE
            ON C2.RN = CTE.RN
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably what the OP really wants, to shuffle the first names in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what possible purpose you would want this for but try using the rand function

```
update personnels 
set first_name =
(select first_name 
from personnels p
where id = (select rand(1 + (RAND() * max(id)))
from personnels p1))
```

i lost count on the brackets but think this is OK to run

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET val =
( SELECT val FROM table table1 WHERE col =
( SELECT RAND( 1+ ( RAND() * MAX(col)))
FROM table table2
)
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).